# JMSTemplate in Spring with 3 differents JMS

Tags: jms, spring-jms

I have 3 differents kind of JMS
IBM MQ Series;
ActiveMQ;
TibcoEMS,

and I have 3 ConnectionFactory and I use a @Conditional to active one of the three, but I wondered if are there any facade or something similar, to avoid have three connectionFactory.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. The `ConnectionFactory` is a way to connect to the broker (see that as a kind of `DataSource` for JMS). So you need them. And you need the 3 clients (i.e. `JmsTemplate`).